# What smartphone and/or app support voice dialing on speakerphone like Moto X 2nd Gen?

Tags: google-play-store, google-now, moto-x, voice-command

My last phone was the Moto X 2nd Gen.  The entire reason I bought the phone was to use its voice command features so I can call for help with my voice.  I'm in a wheelchair, and I refuse to pay for a life line if a smartphone has this capability.

The way the Moto X 2 worked was that you trained a voice command code phrase (with your voice) into the smartphone to unlock the phone.  When utilizing the phone's voice dialing feature, you'd say that code phrase (with your voice) to ***unlock the phone (or bring it out of sleep mode)***, and then say "Call {contact}" where {contact} would be the name of an Google Android contact.  The voice command result(s) get verbally read back to you.  If there are multiple, you have to repeat the correct contact.  It would then dial the primary phone number of that contact while also ***enabling speaker phone***.

I tried the Google Assistant and Google Now and I'm unable to find a way to set things up with all of those features.  Google Now can call someone if you say "Google Now.  Call {contact} on speakerphone.", but you need to wake up your phone from sleep mode before "Google Now" will activate.  I've even tried Open Mic for Google Now, but it doesn't solve anything.

If anyone knows how I can get the features of the Moto X 2 on any other smartphone that has Android installed, or knows of an app with these features, with the use of speakerphone, please let me know.  I also would like to buy a phone with high quality microphone and audio hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the Moto Z has the Moto Voice feature, and the Nexus 5, Nexus 6 and Nexus 6P can be taken out of sleep mode using Google Now.  Other phones using Google Now cannot be taken out of sleep mode.  You must first touch the screen.  So Google Now is useless as a life line if you cannot physically reach your phone in an emergency and must rely on your voice.

Sleep mode and lock mode are different modes/statuses.  Sleep mode is what happens when your screen goes black while the phone is not being used.  Lock mode is when the phone is ready for authentication (keypad, face, voice, code, etc..), but have taken the phone out of sleep mode by pressing a button.  Some forums say you must first unlock the phone.  This is untrue.  I was able to get Google Now to work with the Samsung Galaxy S7 when the phone was NOT sleeping, but was still locked.  But since Google owns the rights to the Nexus brand, they obviously allow their Google Now to work ALL THE TIME, including when in sleep mode.  That's how they keep the edge.  And that's why I'm buying a Nexus 6P now.

Google Pixel phone (new Google phone) might do the same thing, but I haven't looked into it yet.  That phone is a bit more expensive.

It's possible that Google signed some contract with Motorola that allows them to share the patent.  Or maybe Google pays them to use it with their phones.  Because Motorola makes the Nexus 6.